# Tomcat axis web service client read timeout. Timeout configuration

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, client, axis

I have a socket read timeout in Tomcat web app accessing a remote web service. The timeout is exactly 10 minutes. I have trouble finding the configuration responsible for this. Is that some kind of default?

Edit: I use Apache Axis 1.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from DEFAULT_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT in org.apache.axis.Constants

```
/**
 * The default timeout for messages.
 *
 * @since Axis1.2
 */
public static final int DEFAULT_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT=60*1000*10;
```

used in org.apache.axis.MessageContext

```
/**
 * Maximum amount of time to wait on a request, in milliseconds.
 */
private int          timeout = Constants.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT;
```

So it seems a kind of default.

Answer (score 1):

In your case timeouts might be set in Axis configuration. See [Timeout Configuration](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config).

Or try to set your timeout programatically ([Axis client options](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html))

Comment: The links you posted are for Axis2. I use axis 1.4

Answer (score 0):

I found a link here: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/client-side-axis.html#AxisProperties, it mentions CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY but does not specify any default on it.